# Splitting partitions in windows 7 questions

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

I have recently brought a new laptop which has one 500gb hard drive and I would like to partition the main partition into two partitions. One for system and one for documents/music/photos... would shrinking this main partition using the built in partitioning tool achieve this?

Also would defragging allow all the free space to be used if I chose to partition the hard drive in this way? as currently it only allows about half to be used.

Is partitioning a hard drive in this way good? What are your suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> would shrinking this main partition
>   using the built in partitioning tool
>   achieve this?

in a word, yes.

and defragmenting the drive first helps in a way, you will get contiguous free space.

> Is partitioning a hard drive in this
>   way good?

main benefit: you can 'ghost' your system drive and always restore the computer from that image without losing data on the second partition. (now this is no excuse for not having a proper backup :)

Comment: +1 Yes, definitely two partitions is a very good thing. It's disappointing PC manufacturers still won't deliver PCs like this; leaving you to wave goodbye to your documents if you have to use the recovery disc is ridiculous. However, you should still back up before using a partition resizer, because they're not always 100% solid.